# mongodb group by min

Tags: mongodb, group-by, min

I have a table:

```
id   value   date
1      1     2014-08-10 10:00:00
1      2     2014-08-10 10:05:00
1      1     2014-08-10 12:00:00
1      1     2014-08-11 12:05:00
1      2     2014-08-11 12:06:00
2      2     2014-08-10 10:00:00
2      2     2014-08-11 10:05:00
2      1     2014-08-11 12:00:00
2      1     2014-08-20 12:05:00
2      2     2014-08-20 12:06:00
```

and i want to get the total number of value for each id for the first day. I can do it in MySQL using the following command:

```
SELECT test.id, COUNT(CASE WHEN value=1 THEN 1 END) AS 'total_value_1',
                COUNT(CASE WHEN value=2 THEN 1 END) AS 'total_value_2'
FROM test,    
(SELECT id, date(min(date)) as firstDay
 FROM test
 GROUP BY id) AS temp
WHERE  test.id = temp.id AND date(test.date) = temp.firstDay
GROUP BY test.id;
```

Result is:

```
id total_value_1 total_value_2
1         2           1
2         0           1
```

How can i do this in MongoDB?

Comment: I decided not to use MongoDB, but I still wonder the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through the aggregation framework where you use **[a collection of operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)** to define and manipulate documents in pipeline stages that will give you the desired results. Your first pipeline stage is the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator where you would transform your value fields for easier manipulation in the later pipeline stages. The equivalent SQL for this operation is:

```
SELECT id, date, CASE WHEN value=1 THEN 1 END AS 'value_1',
                 CASE WHEN value=2 THEN 1 END AS 'value_2'
FROM test
```

The next pipeline stages use [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) and [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operators to calculate the minimum day of the month on the date field and the sum aggregates on the transformed value fields:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {        
        "$project": {  
            "id": 1,            
            "date": 1,            
            "value_1": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$value", 1 ] }, 1, 0] },
            "value_2": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$value", 2 ] }, 1, 0] }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "id": "$id",
                "date": "$date"
            },
            "minimumDayofMonth": {
                "$min": { "$dayOfMonth": "$date"}
            },
            "total1" : {
                "$sum": "$value_1"
            },
            "total2" : {
                "$sum": "$value_2"
            }             
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "id": "$_id.id",
                "day": "$minimumDayofMonth"
            }, 
            "firstDay": { "$min": "$minimumDayofMonth"  },            
            "total_value_1" : {
                "$sum": "$total1"
            },
            "total_value_2" : {
                "$sum": "$total2"
            }            
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.id",             
            "result": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }                
        }
    },
    {        
        "$project": {  
            "_id": 0,
            "id": "$_id",
            "total_value_1": "$result.total_value_1",
            "total_value_2": "$result.total_value_2"
        }
    }    
])
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "total_value_1" : 0,
            "total_value_2" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "total_value_1" : 2,
            "total_value_2" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I tried the query by changing the dates. I think there is a problem in "$min": { "$dayOfMonth": "$date"}. When I changed the minumum date in table or converted the min to max. I get the same result. In addition, when I write min dayOfMonth, wouldn't it return the minimum day in all months? For example: "2014-08-10", "2014-10-01".